# preg_replace n times a matching string?

Tags: php, preg-replace

this should be very simple question, but i cant get it working for some reason, my framework is PHALCON

```
$string='GuGuSy';
```

i want this to be replaced as

```
$output = 'AAB';
```

so I coded it as:

```
 public function graha($planet)
    {
            if(strpos($planet,'Sy')!==false){
                $planet = preg_replace("/Sy/",'B',$planet);
            }
            if(strpos($planet,'Gu')!==false){
                $planet = preg_replace("/Gu/",'A',$planet);
                    //str_replace("Gu",'A',$planet);
            }
      return $planet;
  }
```

but output I get is not correct, why?

**My output is for the string is "A" only why ?**

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://ideone.com/roEhDX

Comment: could be a problem in the how phalcon framework produce the output, external to this or some php related server issue like preg not installed

Comment: yes issue was phalcon it self see my answer below

Comment: You shouldn't use `preg_replace` to replace simple strings. `preg_replace` should be used with regular expressions. Use `str_replace` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to the Phalcon framework it self

when you return values it seems to use the last returned value only in VOLT templating system. So what you have to do it echo $planet in the function to get the correct value displayed in the phalcon-volt system.

Answer (score -1):

```
$string='GuGuSy';

function graha($planet)
{
$a='';   
if(strpos($planet,'Sy')!==false){
$a= $planet = preg_replace("/Sy/",'B',$planet); // $planet=GuGuB
}

if(strpos($planet,'Gu')!==false){
$a= preg_replace("/Gu/",'A',$planet);

}
return $a;       
}

echo graha($string);
```

Comment: This is not correct. The second replacement will ignore the first replacement because it starts with `$planet` instead of `$a`.

Comment: please copy and past here [link](http://phpfiddle.org) and put any $string='SyGuSyGuSyGuSySy';  you'll get right output as he wanted.

Comment: I didn't see that you assign `$a = $planet = `. Why do you need both variables if you're always setting them to the same thing?

Comment: if `$planet` doesn't contain `Sy` or `Gu`, you return an empty `$a`.

Comment: please have a look the answer putted comments //  $planet=GuGuB   actually $planet variable overwrite and also $a will not return empty